# arc4random - 8 buttons overlapping

Tags: xcode, overlapping, arc4random

I am building an app in which I have 8 UI buttons given all random co ordinates using arc4random. Been trying to figure out how to stop them overlapping.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciate it as it is the only thing holding back my app!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of possible locations that don't overlap:

```
CGPoint possibleLocations[] = {
    { 0, 0 },
    { 25, 25 },
    { 25, 50 },
    // etc.
}

int numLocations = sizeof(possibleLocations) / sizeof(CGPoint);
BOOL takenLocations[numLocations];

CGPoint finalLocation;
int index;

while ((takenLocations[index = arc4random_uniform(numLocations]))
{
}

takenLocations[index] = YES;
finalLocation = possibleLocations[index];
```

Comment: Ah yes! Of course. And thanks for such a quick reply. Been trying to implement this into my code but have been getting very little. Where in the extract above do i include the buttons?

Comment: Can anyone please help? Im really struggling!